# Cancelling scheduled executor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I currently have a scheduled executor which sends out a message after a delay like this:

```
        executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                emitter.emit( message );
            }
        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I need to have another thread which will listen for a cancel message which will send a different message and I need to stop the above message from sending. If no cancel message is received the above sends as normal. Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by using the return value of

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         emitter.emit( message );
     }
    }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
future.cancel(true);  //true if task should be interrupted
```

or by using the shutdown() method of the executor.
Take a look at [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)()
and [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-)()

Answer (score 1):

[Executor#shutdown();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) or [Executor#shutdownNow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)