# How to fire/schedule an event after 12 hours in java

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

We are developing travel application for booking flight, bus tickets etc. For the flight tickets initially PNR (Passenger Name Record) will be generated, through that PNR confirmation of ticket will be done.

The problem is, if ticket is not confirmed with in 12 hours after generating the PNR, the PNR has to be canceled. If not, we will face penalty from Air GDS provider.

Up to now we have written Cron Schedulers which does this thing for every 15 minutes. We have problems by doing like this, and faced penalty also. I can't run the schedulers every minute.

How can I cancel the PNR, after generating 12 hours if not booked.

Comment: It seems your problem is not HOW to fire an event. But more like _even if you fire events you get to suffer penalty_. Any scheduler be it Quartz or Java Timer or Cron -- works the same way, they fire/trigger the even at specified time.

Comment: then, how can i do my requirement in effective way by using schedulers.

Comment: @Eswar - You can consult my answer if you're interested in a non event-driven approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aioobe provided some good references for solving this sort of problem.  However if you want to solve the problem without having to worry about timers or other transient things that may disappear on you if the JVM ever needs to be shutdown and restarted, I'd suggest also considering a simple approach along the lines of:

```
public class PNRExpirationThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {  //or while !stop, or while Server.isRunning(), you get the idea
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);  //wait 30 seconds; adjust this to your liking
                //it's pseudo-SQL, but you get the idea; I'm assuming your data model has the required fields for this to work
                Database.executeTxn("DELETE FROM pnrRecords WHERE NOW() - createDate > 12h AND confirmed = 0");  
            }
            catch (Throwable ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add to your server's startup/initialization routine some code like:

```
//keep a reference to this if you want to terminate the thread gracefully at shutdown time
new PNRExpirationThread().start();
```

Then your platform will automatically query for and delete any records that are older than 12 hours, at 30-second intervals.

Comment: thanks for giving solution. I can achieve my requirement with the above solution. But is it good way. May i know Pros and Crons of above solution

Answer (score 7):

Since this is tagged Java I recommend you to look into one of the following

- The [`java.util.Timer` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)
- [The Quartz library](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

These are the standard solutions to scheduling tasks that are to be executed in the future.

Comment: it is not clear if his problem is 'how to do it in java?' but it seems even if he fires events he suffers penalty.

Answer (score 3):

Ontop of aioobe suggestions, I'd also have a look at the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [Cancelling scheduled executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178205/cancelling-scheduled-executor) because I'm pretty sure that would be the next question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `Timer` and `TimerTask`.

```
 1. Write the code to fire an event in Timertask. 
 2. Schedule the TimerTask after 12 hours using schedule() method.
```

Comment: What happens if the JVM is restarted after a timer is created but before it fires?  12 hours is a long time to wait.  Any approach that uses non-persistent timers for this sort of task is asking for trouble, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Have you checked for asynchronous job scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

[Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) allows you to schedule a task for execution after some delay (in your case 12 hours). However, it is not guaranteed to execute at the desired point in time. From the docs:

> This class does not offer real-time guarantees: it schedules tasks
>   using the Object.wait(long) method.

It may or may not work out as you want.