# Change scheduleWithFixedDelay delay (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

A library I am making requires that a user enters a delay in the constructor of an object. I would like to make it so they don't have to enter the delay in the constructor (I don't want to use multiple constructors) and the delay is set to a default value and can be changed later via a method. This would be easy if I started the thread by another method later on but I want the thread to be started in the constructor.

Is there a way to either cancel a runnable that is being executed or change the delay of it?

Example code:

```
public ExampleClass(Object value1, Object value2) {
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public void cangeDelay(int delay) {
    //what to do here?
}

private class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  When you say, "I don't want to use multiple constructors." That makes me think you might be looking for this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: "Is there a way to either cancel a runnable that is being executed or change the delay of it?"  A Runnable does not have a "delay".  If _your_ runnable has one, it's because you added it.

Comment: @jameslarge I want it to be easy to use and the default value would be what is desired 99% of the time but I would also like it to be configurable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling scheduled executor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178205/cancelling-scheduled-executor)

Answer (score 0):

scheduleWithFixedDelay() returns a Future, f.  You can call f.cancel(), and then schedule the task again at the different rate.